# Calculate past 12 and 6 month Average

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The excel user will export the data from an online website to excel (12 months data), so the data will be all the time different.

I need the ***past 6 months and 12 months average*** (*However, the calculation need to use the months I have in the data, and sometimes there will be less then 6 or 12 months*), but I still need to get the average and frequency for it , however, I am not sure how to get it.

I am trying to write a code, but it is not complete and is not working as well, I don't get an error; it just doesn't work.

I am open for Excel formulas as well, the problem may be the last row and that it need to use the data I have to calculate and not 6 and 12 months full.

PS: I post  a similar question on https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/1227312-dynamic-way-to-calculate-the-last-6-months-average/

Comment: Can you show a sample of the downloaded data? This would help to understand the problem. Also, when you say you need to calculate the *frequency* what precisely do you mean by that?

Comment: @AlexP I add a pic with part of the data, I hope you can get a idea from it (column F is the amount in USD that I need), may to count the frequency the column with the names N will do.

Comment: @AlexP the _frequency_ I mean how many transactions was made per month. However, the frequency I need is the last 12 and 6 months (but only calculating the months that I have on data). I was using this excel formula `=COUNTIFS('12 Months'!A:A,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-6),'12 Months'!A:A,"<"&TODAY()+1)` but here it counts the transactions in the past 6 months (therefore, I need frequency average in the past 12 and  6 month in data months and not in calendar year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will This formulas work for you?
Average for last 6 months:

`=AVERAGEIF(A:A;">="&EDATE(MAX(A:A);-6);B:B)`

Frequency for last 6 months:

```
=IF(MONTH(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))>=6;COUNTIF(A:A;">="&EDATE(MAX(A:A);-6))/6;COUNTIF(A:A;">="&MIN(A:A))/MONTH(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)))
```

Average for last 12 months:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A;">="&EDATE(MAX(A:A);-12);B:B)
```

Frequency for last 12 months:

```
=IF(MONTH(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))>=12;COUNTIF(A:A;">="&EDATE(MAX(A:A);-12))/12;COUNTIF(A:A;">="&MIN(A:A))/MONTH(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)))
```

Comment: the formula for frequency seems to worked, thank you. However, the formula for Average 6 and 12 months did not work, I may be doing something wrong `=AVERAGEIF(('12 Months'!A:A),">="&EDATE(MAX('12 Months'!A:A),-6),('12 Months'!F:F))` which column should I put on row A:A and B:B date or amount? here **('12 Months'!A:A)** is my date column and **('12 Months'!F:F)** is Amount column.

Comment: I mean the formula for average seems to be calculating the full year calendar and I need it do the same way that frequency formula is doing and calculate past 12 and 6 month only using the data I have.

Comment: Formula above count averege amount in last 6 months.  Meybe Formula below will be ok for you `=IF(MONTHS(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))>=6;SUMIF(A:A;">="&EDATE(MAX(A:A);-6);B:B)/6;SUMIF(A:A;">="&EDATE(MAX(A:A);-6);B:B)/MONTHS(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)))`    A:A-  Date column,  B:B - Amount Column

Comment: Try this :) (I wrote MONTHS instead of MONTH)   `=IF(MONTH(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))>=6;SUMIF(A:A;">="&EDATE(MAX(A:A);-6);B:B)/6;SUMIF(A:A;">="&EDATE(MAX(A:A);-6);B:B)/MONTH(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)))`